# Connecting to GDAX websocket api using socket.io with webpack

Tags: webpack, websocket, socket.io, gdax-api

I want to connect to the GDAX websocket api with an in browser application built with react and webpack.  I cannot use the offiicial gdax-node or gdax-toolkit api's because they are not compatible with webpack.  I decided to try connecting to the websocket myself using socket.io, but the code below never establishes a connection.  In the code below my "subscribing" log message after connect never appears.  How do I get this code to connect or at least show an error message?

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');

var subscribe = {
  "type": "subscribe",
  "channels": [{"name": "ticker", "product_ids": ["BTC-EUR"]}]
};

function subscribeToTimer(cb) {
  console.log('Opening socket');
  var socket = io.connect('wss://ws-feed.gdax.com');

  socket.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('Subscribing');

    socket.on('disconnect', function(socket) {
      console.log('Clinet disconnected.');
    });    
  });

  //socket.on('message', timestamp => cb(null, timestamp));
  socket.on('message', data => { console.log(data); });
  socket.on('error', data => { console.log(data); });
}
export { subscribeToTimer };
```

Comment: How are you calling `subscribeToTimer`? With your current code example, we won't know how this piece of code is invoked.

Comment: Just something like this.  When I run the code I can see that the function is being involked because I see the "Opening socket" message, but 
 not the "Subscribing" or "Client disconnected" messages.

subscribeToTimer((err: Error, input: TradeMessage) => this.addRow(input));

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io is not the appropriate library to use for this.  I switched it to using global's websocket and it works fine.

```
function subscribeToTimer(cb) {
  console.log('Opening socket');
  const socket = new WebSocket('wss://ws-feed.gdax.com');

  socket.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    console.log('new message', event.data);
  });

  socket.addEventListener('open', function(event) {
    console.log('Subscribing');


    var subscribe = '{"type": "subscribe", "channels": [{"name": "ticker", "product_ids": ["BTC-EUR"]}]}';
    socket.send(subscribe);

    socket.addEventListener('close', function(event) {
      console.log('Client disconnected.');
    });    
  });

  //socket.addEventListener('message', timestamp => cb(null, timestamp));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since gdax only exposed the `wss` url to public and socket.io does not support `wss` or `ws` connection, we have to find work around. Here `global.websocket` is enough to make connection in the browser. Or you could also check out this [library](https://github.com/heineiuo/isomorphic-ws). It simply wraps the `ws` package and when you build by webpack for browser usage, it will replace the main by `browser.js`.