# connect 2 websockets ws and socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm getting data from a web page with websocket but I need to deploy it with socketIO to client. In my server.js client connects with socketio well but after that data(line1 line2) can't comes properly, always I need to restart server 2-3 times.Then it comes.

Here is my declerations

```
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
const WebSocket = require('ws')
const wss = new WebSocket('gettingDataAdress');

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   console.log("client connected");


   wss.on('open', () => {
       console.log("send processing");
        //line1
   })
   wss.on('message', () => {
       console.log("getting message processing");
       //line2
   })
```

After restarting my server.js 2-3 times it can comes to line1 and line2 , it can't directly.However whenever I comment the socketio Part(I mean only websocket working) it works perfect.How can I do that ? Thank you

Comment: I think you are mixing up socket.io with plain web sockets, just use one, in your case socket.io

Comment: Could you please show all the code include the declaration of `wss` ?

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru I have to use websocket to get data and post with socketio

Comment: @edkeveked I'm editting code you can check it

Comment: wss and socket.io runs on different ports?

Comment: I believe they are at same port at 3000 , if it woudln't I guess it couldn't at even once?It works after close open node server.js 2 - 3 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using two different websockets `ws` and `socket.io`. Use only one to connect to the client and subscribe to the coming messages

### Only Socket.io

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   console.log("client connected");


   socket.on('open', () => {
       console.log("send processing");
        //line1
   })
   socket.on('message', () => {
       console.log("getting message processing");
       //line2
   })
```

### Only ws

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket('url');

ws.on('open', () => {
  //do processing
});

ws.on('message', () => {
  //do processing
});
```

Comment: But the data provider gives the data with websocket I have to connect them ?Can I do it with socket io because provider links like ws://http

Comment: Definitely, you can. You simply need to use the correct url to subscribe with socket.io

Comment: Do I need to define 2,  const wss = new WebSocket("''); because one for api provider one for my client ?

Comment: Yes you can do that since they won't listen using the same url

Comment: Thank you whenever i try i ll share the result with you thank you

Comment: By the way in my server.js
const wss = new WebSocket('wss://http://localhost:3000');
How the url shoud be for the client ?

Comment: I tried but I guess I'm wrong with url and port, should the port same with nodejs server port like 3000 ?  Because it says Error: socket hang up
const wss = new WebSocket('wss://provider');
const wss2 = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');

Answer (score 0):

*wanted to write a comment but had no reputation to write, so decide write on here. sorry!*

If you want to subscribe, rather use `socket.io-client`. However, `socket-io` itself is not a proper library to subscribe `wss`.

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1208

> actually, Socket.IO is not a WebSocket implementation, it has its own protocol which may use a WebSocket connection to transmit data 
>   -darrachequesne-(most contributor of socket-io client library)

so If you get data from wss page, then use ws library and spread it by socket-io. I believe that what you are doing is pretty fine. might need to fix a bit though.

[Connecting to GDAX websocket api using socket.io with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48835447/connecting-to-gdax-websocket-api-using-socket-io-with-webpack)
there is similar question to get data from ws.